# SQLite and Multiple Users

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

I have a C# Winforms application.  Part of the application pulls the contents of a SQLite table and displays it to the screen on a datagridview.  I seem to have a problem where multiple users/computers are using the application.

When the program loads, it opens a single connection to the SQLite DB engine, which remains open until the user exits the program.  On load, it refreshes the table in question and continues to do so at regular intervals.  The table correctly updates when one user is using it or if that one user has more than one instance of the program open.  If, however, more than one person uses it, the table doesn't seem to reflect changes made by other users until the program is closed and reopened.

An example - the first user (user A) logs in.  the table has 5 entries.  they add one to it.  there are now 6 entries.  User B now logs in and sees 6 entries.  User A enters another record, for a total of 7.  User B sees 6 even after the automatic refresh.  And won't see 7 until they close out and reopen the program.  User A sees 7 without any issue.

Any idea what could be causing this problem?  It has to be something related to the DB engine for SQLite as I'm 100% sure my auto refresh is working properly.  I suspect it has something to do with the write-ahead-logging feature or the connection pooling (which I have enabled).  I disabled both to see what would happen, and the same issue occurs.

Comment: Try and do some experiements via the command line or native layer - it should be thread safe:  http://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html (not sure about what the managed layer does)

Comment: Network fileshares don't sync correctly unless you close and re-open periodically. sqlite probably has some protections to avoid corrupting data but I can see how this could get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a file lock issue - the first application may be taking an exclusive write lock, blocking out the other application instances. If this is true, then SQLite's may be simply waiting until the lock is released before updating the data file, which is not an ideal behaviour, but then again using SQLite for multi-user applications is also not ideal.

I have [found](http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html) hints that SHARED locks can (or should in the most recent version) be used. This may be a simple solution, but documentation of this is not easy to find (probably because this bends the specification of SQLite too far?)

Despite this however, it may be better to serialize file access yourself. And this depends on your precise system architecture, in how you should best approach such a feature.

Your system architecture is not clear from your description. You speak of "multiple users/computers" accessing the SQLite file.

If the multiple computers requirement is implemented using network share of the SQLfile, then this is indeed going to be a growing problem. A better architecture or another RDBMS would be advisable.

If multiple computers are accessing the data through a server process (or multiple server processes on the same machine?), then a simple Monitor lock (lock keyword), or ReaderWriterLock will help (in the case of multiple server processes an OS mutex would be required).

**Update**

Given your original question, the above still holds true. However given your situation, looking at your root problem - no access to your businesses RDBMS, I have some other suggestions:

1. Maria DB / mySQL / postgreSQL on your PC - of course this would require your PC to be kept on.
2. Some sort of database and/or service layer hosted in a datacentre (there are many options here, such as VPS, Azure DB, shared hosting DB etc.., of course all incurring a cost [perhaps there are some small free ones out there])

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  The application is stored and runs from a network location so all users modify the same database file.  The only reason I am using SQLite instead of my company's SQL database is because I am not a professional developer so it is a pain to get write access to the SQL database.  The purpose of this database file was just so that all users could see what is currently running in the system to help with workflow so I didn't see it as a mandatory feature that required me to jump through the hoops to get write access.  I'll have to carefully consider my next steps.

Comment: Ah yes, a common issue in IT, keen users fixing problems but without the support of enterprise infrastructure - this is something I'm looking to address in the industry. Aside from that, you may want to consider a "cloud" database (which you will need to pay a small monthly fee for), cloud = flexible cloud or simply a datacentre hosted database instance - you can even rent something like a Linode   (Linux) or other windows VPS and have full control of your own "server", but anything less than that would also do.

Comment: After sleeping on this, I think I know what I will do.  It's not elegant at all, but it will work.  I am going to make it so that all sql code that requires write access will be appended to a text file.  only one instance of the program will be able to claim write access and it will maintain that write privilege until it's closed.  i'll use a file monitor to be notified of changes and then sweep the file and execute the sql code.  all the other instances will simply run a check to see if the DB file is locked before running non-write statements and wait if required.  not pretty, but solves it.

Comment: Given that you are going to this sort of effort. How about you find/build a class which synchronizes access based simply on write access of a separate empty network file. Alternatively you could possibly use a udp broadcast or multicast algorithm similar to csma to compete for write access.

Comment: i was thinking exactly along the lines of a separate empty network file.  that's probably the easiest thing for me to do.  i'm not familiar with how to do UDP broadcasting.  I was planning on building a SQLiteManager class to take care of all the DB concurrency issues.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite across network file systems is not a great solution. You'll find that the FAQ and [Appropriate Uses](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html) pages gently steer you away from using SQLite as a concurrently accessed database across an NFS.

While in theory it *could* work, the implementation and latency of network file systems dramatically increases the chance of locking conflicts occurring during write actions.

I should point out that reading the database creates a read-only lock, which is fine for concurrent access.

Comment: good to know that reading creates a read-only lock.  i will keep that in mind when going forward with my (non-elegant) solution that i detailed out in response to Todd.  if i test for a write lock instead of any file lock this will greatly improve performance.  of course, with the current database as it is and the speed of sqlite, it won't be noticeable, but i still want to code it efficiently since the higher ups like what i'm doing have told me they eventually want to make this available to all global teams and not just mine.  taking the easy route could end up costing me later on.  thanks.